# Group by multiple fields in Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have an aggregation operation criteria, and at some point, I need to group by two fields, but one of them is a nested field inside the object. I have this:

```
criteria.add(group("name", "amount.currency").count().as("number"))
```

But I get this error

> FieldPath field names may not contain '.'

How can I group by multiple fields including nested ones in Spring Data MongoDB

Comment: `Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("a", "a.b").count().as("count"))` does seem to work. Which version are you using. Can you add the Stracktrace and how you set up the entire `Aggregation`.